# PHP while loop memory error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate > 32 bytes) in path/to/1phpquery.php on > line 24

Line 24 is

> while ($r = $mysqli->query($query)) {

The full code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$instr = "CCBOT";
require("dbconnect.php");

$query = 'SELECT LgSpecNet, SmSpecNet, CommNet FROM cot WHERE Ticker = "$instr" LIMIT 5';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Large Spec Net', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Small Spec Net', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Commercial Net', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();

while ($r = $mysqli->query($query)) { 
$temp = array();

$ra = $r->fetch_assoc();    

$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $ra['LgSpecNet']);
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $ra['SmSpecNet']);
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $ra['CommNet']);

$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$result->free();

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;

}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Reduce the amount of data you're fetching, or increase PHP's memory limit... Any reason you have to build that intermediate array anyways? can't you just do `$rows[] = $r`?

Comment: habitually, you fetch the result in the while (...->fetch()), you don't repeat the "query" over and over and over.

Comment: Thank you.  Mark B, it's only asking for 5 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're endlessly re-running your query.  Change

```
while ($r = $mysqli->query($query))
```

To

```
while ($ra = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

And remove the line:

```
$ra = $r->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did solve that problem. I'll mark it as the answer.  The JSON is returning: {"cols":[{"label":"Large Spec Net","type":"number"},{"label":"Small Spec Net","type":"number"},{"label":"Commercial Net","type":"number"}],"rows":[]}      ... the rows are empty.  I tested the query before this and it returns 5 rows.  Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't returning rows, so I'll figure that out.  Thanks again.  I avoided asking a question for three days since they're all answered somewhere online. This was a big help.